# Why did I get insurance payout without dying?

Tags: phasmophobia

I just played a solo round of Phasmophobia on Professional difficulty, correctly identified the ghost and left within a few minutes, all without ever getting any ghost activity higher than Lv 2. Despite this, when finishing the mission, I got $10 insurance payout. Why?

[image: Results showing $10 Insurance payout]

From my understanding, insurance gives you 50% of the money of lost equipment on Amateur difficulty and 25% money back on intermediate difficulty upon death. Professional is supposed to pay out nothing.

---

Edit: I played three more solo games, two on Amateur difficulty, one on Intermediate, and all three rewarded $10 insurance payout despite me not dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a glitch with an unknown cause that provides solo players an occasional $10 payout. Of the few [recorded instances](https://steamcommunity.com/app/739630/discussions/0/3008927444649276971/) of people getting this bonus they were all playing solo mode and all received the same insurance amount of $10. One user [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PhasmophobiaGame/comments/jr41wg/just_got_insurance_money_without_dying_solo/) say that your items may have been lost, and the insurance is covering those losses but other users claim that they still have their full inventory.

All in all, it appears to be a random $10 bonus for people playing alone. Perhaps try thinking you stole some cash the homeowner left behind.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for now until a full explanation is provided